# Check if first child renders nothing in Native Testing Library

Tags: react-native, native-testing-library

Suppose I have the following component:

```js
const MyComponent = () => null;
```

In React Testing Library (RTL), the following, AFAIK, should work:

```js
const { container } = render(<MyComponent />);

expect(container.firstChild).toBeEmpty();
```

where `.toBeEmpty` is a custom matcher from `jest-dom`. However, in NTL, `container.firstChild` is not defined so I can't use `.toBeEmpty` matcher from `jest-native`. After some experimentation, I got it to work as follows:

```js
expect(container.children[0]).toBeUndefined();
```

Is there any other, possibly better, way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a situation like so:

```
function PhotoComponent({policy}) {
  if (policy === 'unavailable')
    return null;
  
  return (<View />);
}
```

Tested like this:

```
it("should not render if policy is 'unavailable'", () => {
  const {toJSON} = render(<PhotoComponent policy={'unavailable'} />);
  const children = toJSON().children;
  expect(children.length).toBe(0);
});
```

Some times you will want to filter the children like, for instance:

```
const children = toJSON().children.filter(
  (child) => child.type === 'View' || child.type === 'Modal'
);
```

Keep calm and Happy coding!